# Как исправить ошибку отступа ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Изменение размерности у `X_train` успешно компилируется, но ничего не меняя при изменении размерности у `Y_train` выдаёт ошибку:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

```
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

nsamples, nx, ny = X_train.shape # место возникновения ошибки
X_train = X_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

nsamples, nx, ny = Y_train.shape
Y_train = Y_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

model = LGBMClassifier(objective='multiclass')
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,categorical_feature=[0,3])
```

Comment: Указанную в вопросе ошибку вызывает строка: `samples, nx, ny = Y_train.shape`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

уберите строки:

```
nsamples, nx, ny = Y_train.shape
Y_train = Y_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

т.к. они не имеют смысла.

`Y_train` - это одномерный вектор правильных значений для обучения модели:

```
In [62]: Y_train.shape
Out[62]: (60000,)

In [63]: Y_train[:5]
Out[63]: array([5, 0, 4, 1, 9], dtype=uint8)
```

поэтому у него только один компонент в размерности `.shape`, который вы пытаетесь присвоить сразу трем переменным - это вызывает указанную вами ошибку.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [64]: a,b,c = (60000,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a5b9b64c3fb7> in <module>
----> 1 a,b,c = (60000,)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

---

Если вы изменяете размерность обучающей выборки, то и тестовую выборку надо изменить таким же способом:

```
test_samples, nx, ny = X_test.shape # место возникновения ошибки
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1, nx*ny))
```